# Media upload in add comment meta box

Tags: images, comments, uploads

Is there a way to add media uploader to add comments meta box in post edit screen? For logged in author to be able to post image in comment from back-end.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could start with this :

```
add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_after', 'wpse_102612_additional_fields' );// only for logged users

function wpse_102612_additional_fields () {
echo '<p class="comment-form-upload">'.
'<label for="upload">' . __( 'Upload your file' ) . '</label>'.
'<input id="upload" name="upload" type="file" size="30" /></p>';

}
```